# Dynamic site using R Selenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scrape some financial reports from the SEC Edgar databases: https://www.sec.gov/oiea/Article/edgarguide.html

As it's dynamic, I'm using R Selenium on Firefox and now I'm a bit stuck. Firefox is open and I've navigated to the right page.

I'm after total assets.

```
    remDr$navigate("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000001800&type=10-K&dateb=&owner=include&count=40&search_text=")
    webElem1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#interactiveDataBtn")
    webElem1$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
    webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#menu_cat3")
    webElem2$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
    webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#r6 .xbrlviewer")
    webElem3$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
    webElem4 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#idp6852922048 > tbody > tr:nth-child(12) > td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()
```

As you can see I'm trying to use a mix of RSelenium and rvest to retrieve the value but all I'm getting is:

```
    Error in UseMethod("xml_text") : 
    no applicable method for 'xml_text' applied to an object of class "c('webElement', 
    'remoteDriver', 'errorHandler', 'envRefClass', '.environment', 'refClass', 'environment', 'refObject')"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `class(webElem4)` you will see it is (not surprisingly) an object of class `webElement`. This is a special S4 class with its own methods defined. You are passing it to `html_text` as if it were an `html_node`, as defined in `xml2` (or `rvest`).

Although the two might seem quite similar, a `webElement` represents a pointer to an actively rendered node in a browser, not just an inert string of text to be parsed. The `rvest` and `xml2` packages have no concept of what a `webElement` is or how to read it.

Fortunately, they don't need to. The `webElement` class has its own method for extracting text from the associated element. So in your case (using a full worked example with Chrome rather than Firefox):

```r
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, chromever = "84.0.4147.30")$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000001800&type=10-K&dateb=&owner=include&count=40&search_text=")
webElem1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#interactiveDataBtn")
webElem1$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#menu_cat3")
webElem2$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#r6 .xbrlviewer")
webElem3$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
webElem4 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#idp6852922048 > tbody > tr:nth-child(12) > td:nth-child(2)") 
result <- webElem4$getElementText()[[1]]

result
#> [1] "15,667"
```